# TPL Dataflow, guarantee completion only when ALL source data blocks completed

Tags: c#, concurrency, task-parallel-library, tpl-dataflow

How can I re-write the code that the code completes when BOTH transformblocks completed? I thought completion means that it is marked complete AND the " out queue" is empty?

```
public Test()
    {
        broadCastBlock = new BroadcastBlock<int>(i =>
            {
                return i;
            });

        transformBlock1 = new TransformBlock<int, string>(i =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("1 input count: " + transformBlock1.InputCount);
                Thread.Sleep(50);
                return ("1_" + i);
            });

        transformBlock2 = new TransformBlock<int, string>(i =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("2 input count: " + transformBlock1.InputCount);
                Thread.Sleep(20);
                return ("2_" + i);
            });

        processorBlock = new ActionBlock<string>(i =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine(i);
            });

        //Linking
        broadCastBlock.LinkTo(transformBlock1, new DataflowLinkOptions { PropagateCompletion = true });
        broadCastBlock.LinkTo(transformBlock2, new DataflowLinkOptions { PropagateCompletion = true });
        transformBlock1.LinkTo(processorBlock, new DataflowLinkOptions { PropagateCompletion = true });
        transformBlock2.LinkTo(processorBlock, new DataflowLinkOptions { PropagateCompletion = true });
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        const int numElements = 100;

        for (int i = 1; i <= numElements; i++)
        {
            broadCastBlock.SendAsync(i);
        }

        //mark completion
        broadCastBlock.Complete();

        processorBlock.Completion.Wait();

        Console.WriteLine("Finished");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

I edited the code, adding an input buffer count for each transform block. Clearly all 100 items are streamed to each of the transform blocks. But as soon as one of the transformblocks finishes the processorblock does not accept any more items and instead the input buffer of the incomplete transformblock just flushes the input buffer.

Comment: Beware that the transform blocks might not receive all messages from the broadcast block. They only receive the _latest_ message. If the broadcast block is offered messages faster than the transform block can receive them, the transform block will miss messages. Also, you should `await` on `SendAsync(i)` if you want to ensure message order etc.

Comment: @urbanhusky I'm not sure about your assertion that the `TransformBlock` will miss messages.  The docs state that `BroadcastBlock` guarantees that it will propagate to all linked targets before accepting a new item. If `BoundedCapacity` is unbounded on the target, then the target `TransformBlock` will buffer messages.  Now, if `BoundedCapacity` is set, then it will block until there's capacity, and that might result in dropped messages, especially with the unawaited `SendAsync`.  In short, my understanding is that if unbounded, no messages are dropped.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The issue is exactly what casperOne said in his answer. Once the first transform block completes, the processor block goes into “finishing mode”: it will process remaining items in its input queue, but it won't accept any new items.

There is a simpler fix than splitting your processor block in two though: don't set `PropagateCompletion`, but instead set completion of the processor block manually when both transform blocks complete:

```
Task.WhenAll(transformBlock1.Completion, transformBlock2.Completion)
    .ContinueWith(_ => processorBlock.Complete());
```

Comment: exactly what I was looking for. Was not aware that Task.WhenAll returns an awaitable task, my negligence.

Comment: I need the very same, maybe its too late, but could you post an update about where do I need to add the Task.WhenAll construct?

Comment: @AttilaHajdrik Probably at the end of your dataflow setup code, near your `LinkTo`s.

Comment: I've tried that but was not working, but it was 1:30AM...although I've modified my code to plain TPL and separated some tasks and I think I was able to solve it well without DataFlow.

Answer (score 32):

The issue here is that you are setting the [`PropagateCompletion` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/LIBRary/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.dataflowlinkoptions.propagatecompletion%28v=vs.110%29) each time you call the [`LinkTo` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh462751.aspx) to link the blocks and the different in wait times in your transformation blocks.

From the documentation for the [`Complete` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.idataflowblock.complete.aspx) on the [`IDataflowBlock` interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh160365.aspx) (emphasis mine):

> Signals to the IDataflowBlock that it **should not accept** nor produce any more messages **nor consume any more postponed messages**.

Because you stagger out your wait times in each of the [`TransformBlock<TInput, TOutput>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194782.aspx) instances, `transformBlock2` (waiting for 20 ms) is finished before `transformBlock1` (waiting for 50 ms).  `transformBlock2` completes first, and then sends the signal to `processorBlock` which then says "I'm not accepting anything else" (and `transformBlock1` hasn't produced all of its messages yet).

Note that the processing of `transformBlock1` before `transformBlock1` is not *absolutely* guaranteed; it's feasible that the thread pool (assuming you're using the default scheduler) will process the tasks in a different order (but more than likely will not, as it will steal work from the queues once the 20 ms items are done).

Your pipeline looks like this:

```
           broadcastBlock
          /              \
 transformBlock1   transformBlock2
          \              /
           processorBlock
```

In order to get around this, you want to have a pipeline that looks like this:

```
           broadcastBlock
          /              \
 transformBlock1   transformBlock2
          |              |
 processorBlock1   processorBlock2
```

Which is accomplished by just creating two separate [`ActionBlock<TInput>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194684.aspx) instances, like so:

```
// The action, can be a method, makes it easier to share.
Action<string> a = i => Console.WriteLine(i);

// Create the processor blocks.
processorBlock1 = new ActionBlock<string>(a);
processorBlock2 = new ActionBlock<string>(a);


// Linking
broadCastBlock.LinkTo(transformBlock1, 
    new DataflowLinkOptions { PropagateCompletion = true });
broadCastBlock.LinkTo(transformBlock2, 
    new DataflowLinkOptions { PropagateCompletion = true });
transformBlock1.LinkTo(processorBlock1, 
    new DataflowLinkOptions { PropagateCompletion = true });
transformBlock2.LinkTo(processorBlock2, 
    new DataflowLinkOptions { PropagateCompletion = true });
```

You then need to wait on both processor blocks instead of just one:

```
Task.WhenAll(processorBlock1.Completion, processorBlock2.Completion).Wait();
```

A *very* important note here; when creating an `ActionBlock<TInput>`, the default is to have the [`MaxDegreeOfParallelism` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.executiondataflowblockoptions.maxdegreeofparallelism.aspx) on the [`ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.executiondataflowblockoptions.aspx) instance passed to it set to one.

This means that the calls to the [`Action<T>` delegate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/018hxwa8.aspx) that you pass to the `ActionBlock<TInput>` are thread-safe, only one will execute at a time.

Because you now have *two* `ActionBlock<TInput>` instances pointing to the same `Action<T>` delegate, you aren't guaranteed thread-safety.

If your method is thread-safe, then you don't have to do anything (which would allow you to set the `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` property to [`DataflowBlockOptions.Unbounded`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.dataflowblockoptions.unbounded.aspx), since there's no reason to block).

If it's *not* thread-safe, and you need to guarantee it, you need to resort to traditional synchronization primitives, like the [`lock` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz.aspx).

In this case, you'd do it like so (although it's clearly not needed, as the [`WriteLine` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.writeline.aspx) on the [`Console` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.aspx) is thread-safe):

```
// The lock.
var l = new object();

// The action, can be a method, makes it easier to share.
Action<string> a = i => {
    // Ensure one call at a time.
    lock (l) Console.WriteLine(i);
};

// And so on...
```

Comment: Thanks for the lengthy answer, but I chose svick's answer because it directly applies to TPL Dataflow and offers a very concise and simple solution.

Comment: You can easily avoid locking if you use the same [`ExclusiveScheduler`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.concurrentexclusiveschedulerpair.exclusivescheduler) for both action blocks.

Answer (score 9):

An addition to svick's answer: to be consistent with the behaviour you get with the PropagateCompletion option, you also need to forward exceptions in case a preceding block faulted. An extension method like the following takes care of that as well:

```
public static void CompleteWhenAll(this IDataflowBlock target, params IDataflowBlock[] sources) {
    if (target == null) return;
    if (sources.Length == 0) { target.Complete(); return; }
    Task.Factory.ContinueWhenAll(
        sources.Select(b => b.Completion).ToArray(),
        tasks => {
            var exceptions = (from t in tasks where t.IsFaulted select t.Exception).ToList();
            if (exceptions.Count != 0) {
                target.Fault(new AggregateException(exceptions));
            } else {
                target.Complete();
            }
        }
    );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a method that is functionally equivalent to pkt's [`CompleteWhenAll`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13510094/tpl-dataflow-guarantee-completion-only-when-all-source-data-blocks-completed/15898730#15898730) method, but with slightly less code:

```
public static void PropagateCompletion(IDataflowBlock[] sources,
    IDataflowBlock target)
{
    // Arguments validation omitted
    Task allSourcesCompletion = Task.WhenAll(sources.Select(s => s.Completion));
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(async _ =>
    {
        try { await allSourcesCompletion.ConfigureAwait(false); } catch { }

        Exception exception = allSourcesCompletion.IsFaulted ?
            allSourcesCompletion.Exception : null;

        if (exception is null) target.Complete(); else target.Fault(exception);
    });
}
```

Usage example:

```
PropagateCompletion(new[] { transformBlock1, transformBlock2 }, processorBlock);
```

The `PropagateCompletion` method is a variant of a more general method with the same name, that I have posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63748814/many-to-many-tpl-dataflow-does-not-process-all-inputs/63749571#63749571).

Answer (score 1):

Other answers are quite clear about why PropagateCompletion=true mess things up when a block has more than two sources.

To provide a simple solution to the problem, you may want to look at an open source library [DataflowEx](https://github.com/gridsum/dataflowex) that solves this kind of problem with smarter completion rules built-in. (It uses TPL Dataflow linking internally but supports complex completion propagation. The implementation looks similiar to WhenAll but also handles the dynamic link adding. Please check [Dataflow.RegisterDependency()](https://github.com/gridsum/DataflowEx/blob/master/Gridsum.DataflowEx/Dataflow.cs) and [TaskEx.AwaitableWhenAll()](https://github.com/gridsum/DataflowEx/blob/master/Gridsum.DataflowEx/Exceptions/TaskEx.cs) for impl detail.)

I slightly changed your code to make everything work using DataflowEx:

```
public CompletionDemo1()
{
    broadCaster = new BroadcastBlock<int>(
        i =>
            {
                return i;
            }).ToDataflow();

    transformBlock1 = new TransformBlock<int, string>(
        i =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("1 input count: " + transformBlock1.InputCount);
                Thread.Sleep(50);
                return ("1_" + i);
            });

    transformBlock2 = new TransformBlock<int, string>(
        i =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("2 input count: " + transformBlock2.InputCount);
                Thread.Sleep(20);
                return ("2_" + i);
            });

    processor = new ActionBlock<string>(
        i =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine(i);
            }).ToDataflow();

    /** rather than TPL linking
      broadCastBlock.LinkTo(transformBlock1, new DataflowLinkOptions { PropagateCompletion = true });
      broadCastBlock.LinkTo(transformBlock2, new DataflowLinkOptions { PropagateCompletion = true });
      transformBlock1.LinkTo(processorBlock, new DataflowLinkOptions { PropagateCompletion = true });
      transformBlock2.LinkTo(processorBlock, new DataflowLinkOptions { PropagateCompletion = true });
     **/

    //Use DataflowEx linking
    var transform1 = transformBlock1.ToDataflow();
    var transform2 = transformBlock2.ToDataflow();

    broadCaster.LinkTo(transform1);
    broadCaster.LinkTo(transform2);
    transform1.LinkTo(processor);
    transform2.LinkTo(processor);
}
```

Full code is [here](https://github.com/gridsum/DataflowEx/blob/develop/Gridsum.DataflowEx.Demo/ForStackoverflow/CompletionDemo1.cs).

Disclaimer: I am the author of DataflowEx, which is published under MIT license.

Comment: could you please disclose in case you work for Gridsum? My question explicitly mentioned that I need an answer for TPL Dataflow, I did not want to use a third party solution for this problem. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, I work for Gridsum. But the library is completely free and open source so I thought it might help you. No commercial thinking at all. If what you need is about the internal mechanism of TPL Dataflow please do ignore my answer. But if somebody needs a *solution* the answer has its value. Thanks :)

Comment: Updated the answer with a bit more detail. Disclaimer also added.