# Completing a TPL dataflow chain

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library, tpl-dataflow

Given this code:

```
s_Batch = new BatchBlock<PerformanceRecord>(500);
s_Action = new ActionBlock<PerformanceRecord[]>(a => SendToDatabase(a));
s_Batch.LinkTo(s_Action);
```

When I'm done do I need to call `Complete()` on each block? Or will completing `s_Batch` trigger a complete in the blocks linked to it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [TPL Dataflow, guarantee completion only when ALL source data blocks completed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13510094/tpl-dataflow-guarantee-completion-only-when-all-source-data-blocks-completed)

Comment: Does the above answer satisfy your need?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As your code stands now, you need to call `Complete` on all blocks individually:

```
s_Batch.Complete();
await s_Batch.Completion;

s_Action.Complete();
await s_Action.Completion;
```

You could however use `DataflowLinkOptions` while linking the blocks to request completion propagation:

```
s_Batch.LinkTo(s_Action, new DataflowLinkOptions {PropagateCompletion = true});
s_Batch.Complete();
await s_Batch.Completion;
```

This will propagate both completion and faulting notification to the linked target block (i.e. `s_Action`).

Answer (score 1):

I like l3arnon's answer actually since it is the most concise.

This is something else I have done/seen with TPL blocks which also works.

```
s_Batch.Completion.ContinueWith( t => 
    { 
        if(t.IsFaulted) 
            ((IDataFlowBlock)s_Action).Fault(t.Exception);
        else
            s_Action.Complete();
    });
s_Batch.Complete();
s_Action.Completion.Wait();
```

Downside is that you will need to repeat this pattern for each linked block so you end up repeating yourself quite a bit.